# REGEX greediness or just wrong syntax

Tags: java, regex, regex-greedy

I tried to delete all the `[.!?]` from quotes in a text and doing so , I want first to catch all my quotes including `[.!?]` with a regex to delete them after that.

My regex doesn't work, maybe because it's greedy. It takes from my "«" (character at index 569) to the last character which is another "»" (character at index 2730).

My regex was:

```
Pattern full=Pattern.compile("«.*[.!?].*?»");

Matcher mFull = full.matcher(result);
while(mFull.find()){
    System.out.println(mFull.start()+"  "+mFull.end());
}
```

So I got:

```
569   2731
```

Also , Same problem of greediness , with catching sentences ( beginning with any [A-Z]  and ending with any [.!?].

Comment: In order for someone to help you on this, I'd recommend you post the input string and desired output.

Comment: You must be looking for something like `s.replaceAll("(\\G(?!^)|«)([^«».!?]*)[.!?](?=[^«»]*»)", "$1$2")`

Comment: Wow , I'm not very good with regex , can you please explain it ?

Comment: I explained in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56253384/3832970).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
s = s.replaceAll("(\\G(?!^)|«)([^«».!?]*)[.!?](?=[^«»]*»)", "$1$2");
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KOmSdJ/1)

**Details**

- `(\G(?!^)|«)` - Group 1 (whose value is referred to with `$1` from the replacement pattern): either the end of the previous match or `«`
- `([^«».!?]*)` - Group 2 (`$2`): any 0+ chars other than `«`, `»`, `!`, `.` and `?`
- `[.!?]` - any of the three symbols
- `(?=[^«»]*»)` - there must be a `»` after 0 or more chars other than `«` and `»` immediately to the right of the current location.

Comment: thanks for your help ! it works perfectly ! May I ask you too much if I ask you what the regex should be if I want to catch A sentence ( beginning with [A-Z] and ending with [.!?] , i got the same problem of greediness.  Thank you !

Comment: @Benech17 Please bear in mind that regex is natural language grammar unaware. If you use a `(?s)(?:^|[.?!])\s*(A.*?[?!.])` pattern it might work in the majority cases, but will fail when the sentence contains an abbreviation, e.g. `Another U.S. military base was deployed.`

Comment: Yes I know it , but I would do a pretreatment to my text to "recognize" that abbreviation etc...